# (python and jes) How to find the position of a character in a string if 2 characters are the same?

Tags: python, jes

```
def sumNumbers1(num1,num2):
    sum= str(num1+num2)
    print "Sum is " + sum
    for char in sum:
        digit = sum.find(char)+1
        print "Digit " + str(digit) + " is " + char
```

I'm trying to get a function that prints the sum of two numbers, then the first digit of the sum and what that character is, and so on for each digit. However, if the sum is a number with two of the same characters, (77 for example), my function prints "Sum is 77 Digit 1 is 7
 Digit 1 is 7" I realize this is an issue with index but how do I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to use `enumerate`.  `sum` is a string, enumerate will let you iterate over the characters in that string while also returning the index of each character.  Python indexing is 0-based, so if you want the *digit* index to start at 1, you need to add 1 to `i`

```
for i, char in enumerate(sum):
    print "Digit " + str(i+1) + " is " + char
```

Comment: While you are right, we haven't learned enumerate yet but I found a way that works. Thanks a bunch for taking the time to answer this though!

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumNumbers1(num1,num2):
    sum = num1 + num2
    print ("the sum is" , sum)
    s = str(sum)
    for digit,i in enumerate(s,start =1):
        print("digit ", digit, "is", i)

sumNumbers1(2230,20)


def sumNumbers1(num1,num2):

    sum = num1 + num2
    pos = 1
    print ("the sum is" , sum)
    for e in str(sum):
        print ("digit", pos,"is" , e)
        pos += 1       


sumNumbers1(2230,20)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much! However, I did have to convert pos to a string to add it to the string "Digit " and " is "